# How to get the location set by geofire-java in geofire-js

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

We are creating a location tracking application which is implemented both while online as well as offline.
The location of a person is stored using geofire-java API.
Now to access it in offline mode we need to access it using the geofire-js API

Comment: is there any code snippet to understand question better ?

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried so far?